# optimize.leastsq or optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy

I've got to fit a gaussian profile and a lorentzian profile to a set of data. When I use optimize.curve_fit, the fit itself works but I can't calculate the error in it as the following warning comes up:

```
category=OptimizeWarning
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
```

When I use optimize.leastsq, I don't quite understand what parameters I'm supposed to put in the brackets. It tells me I need four parameters, but when I put the four I want it it tells me that two of them aren't defined, but they are the parameters that I need it to find, Eo and Io. Here's my code (E is the x-value of the data):

```
#define gaussian width, print
    gaussianwidth = exp((-E**2)/(2*(stdev**2)))

#define gaussian function
def gaussianfit(Io, Eo, E, gaussianwidth):
    return Io*exp((-(E-Eo)/gaussianwidth)**2)

#plot gaussian
y = opt.leastsq(gaussianfit, Eo, Io, E, I)
print y[0]
print y[1]
#I printed these so I could see what values it throws out (nothing at the mo)
```

Which function would be better and how do I fix either of them? Help please! 
thanks

Comment: There's 100 pairs of data haha...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! New to stack overflow so didn't realise that was a thing! I'll post 20 points below.

Comment: E array: 1
6
11
16
21
26
31
36
41
46
51
56
61
66
71
76
81
86
91
96

Comment: Y array: 2.186931631
2.531706858
3.936814977
8.18617783
13.44208124
31.92798589
44.84743332
27.51194818
21.95777079
12.67691642
6.17605016
4.399482724
2.799830182
1.836529648
1.920741553
0.893236819
0.783444015
1.044172859
0.502287225
0.50369942